# Wait on a variable without blocking

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a c# program where `function1` needs to wait on a variable to become true without blocking the program. `function2` which is called asynchronously from an external script sets the variable to true. Is there a way I can wait midway in `function1` without blocking  `function2` from being called? I need to continue executing rest of `function 1` after `function2` sets the variable to true.

```
 bool doneProcessing;

 public void function1(string someParameter)
 {
   doneProcessing = false;

   InvokeScript(somevalue);

   //Wait till variable doneProcessing becomes true;

   //Continue from here after doneProcessing is true

  }

public void function2(string someParameter)
 {
   doneProcessing = true;

   return;

  }
```

Comment: how the function2 is called? With an event?

Comment: _to wait on a variable to become true without blocking_ - Waiting == Blocking

Comment: Which .Net Framework Version?

Under 4.5: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh156528.aspx

Comment: Could `function1` be called more than once before it finishes processing, if it does, what should happen?

Comment: Can `InvokeScript` be modified at all? How does InvokeScript know to call `function2`?

Comment: TaskCOmpletionSource is your friend

Comment: You cant wait without blocking, you can only do other things while waiting. If you mean that you dont want to block a UI thread just keep checking for done intermittently and do the approprite responce once it changes.

Answer (score 3):

*TaskCompletionSource is your friend*

```
 bool doneProcessing;
 TaskCompletionSource < bool > tcs = new TaskCompletionSource < bool > ();


 public void function1(string someParameter)
 {
     doneProcessing = false;

     Task < bool > b = InvokeScript("IDontCare");
 Console.WriteLine ("What's up?...");
     b.ContinueWith(_ => Console.WriteLine("finished!")); //magic is here
 Console.WriteLine ("Im not blocking...");

 }


 public Task < bool > function2(string someParameter)
 {


 new Thread(()=> {Thread.Sleep(2000); tcs.SetResult(true); /*this simulate putting true in doneProcessing variable*/}).Start();
     return tcs.Task;
 }

 public Task < bool > InvokeScript(string someParameter)
 {
     return function2(someParameter);
 }



 void Main()
 {
     function1("1");
     Console.ReadLine();    
 } 

// output :What's up?...
Im not blocking...
finished
```

Comment: Good example, +1, the only Nit I would make is to make it more like the OP's question "I'm not blocking..." should be in `Main` after `function1` is called so only the "extra stuff" remains in `function1`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain thanks. you are welcome to edit my answer as you desire :-)

Comment: This looks like it could be a solution. But the problem is function 2 is being called from an external script asynchronously. How do I not block the main UI thread while waiting for function 2 to be called and finish?

Comment: I am using .Net 4 :( using "await function2" would have been a perfect solution.

Comment: TaskCompletionSource  is valid for fw4

Answer (score 2):

The easiest ways could be

- pass a delegate into `function2` so when it ends call that function
- or create a custom event (say) `Function2Complete`, and from `function1` subscribe to it.

If this is not what you're asking for, please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

As someone said in the comments, you cannot wait without blocking.
But, you can *wait without waiting*.

It all depends on what exactly you mean by 'wait' word.

Usually, you just want a piece of code to get executed when a set of conditions are met. But this does not mean that you have to block on anything.

Consider this:

```
bool condition1 = false;
bool condition2 = false;
bool condition3 = false;

aFunction1() { condition1 = true; }
aFunction2() { condition2 = true; }
aFunction3() { condition3 = true; }

whenJobHasBeenCompleted() { console.writeline("all three were done!"); }

// and I'd like to have it automagically called..:
if(cond1 && cond2 && cond3) whenJobHasBeenCompleted();
```

So, obviously, I'd like the last function to be executed once all previous have been invoked - but I do not really care who called them and in what order.

There are many tools*) for that, but consider the **easiest and most obvious: plain .Net events**":

```
bool condition1 = false;
bool condition2 = false;
bool condition3 = false;

event eventhandler VariableHasChanged;

aFunction1() { condition1 = true; VariableHasChanged(); }
aFunction2() { condition2 = true; VariableHasChanged(); }
aFunction3() { condition3 = true; VariableHasChanged(); }

VariableHasChanged += whenJobHasBeenCompleted;

whenJobHasBeenCompleted()
{ 
    if( !( condition1 && condition2 && condition3 ) )
       return;

    // VariableHasChanged -= whenJobHasBeenCompleted

    console.writeline("all three were done!");
}
```

This statemachine-like approach is probably the easiest to comprehend. Before taking other more complex tools, please train with it until you get a very good view on what are the pros and cons of this approach.

Now, as I said, there are **many** other ways.

- With events, you will often get problems wiht multithreading and proper cleanup. So, you can use any Eventing/Notification framework like i.e. WeakEvents or CompositeEvents from Prism/CAG and those problems will be probably gone.
- You can create set of (smart)properties and Bind to them instead of using events. If using any XAMLish UI, you can easily write a trigger/multibinding that will observe three sources and react only when all three are set.
- You can take a worker thread and condition variables (or you can use TaskCompletionSource as Royi suggested, which hides most of it from you).
- You can fetch `Rx Framework` and use hot-observable instead of variables and join/filter them to create a filtered event stream that pings only when all three variables are set to certain value.
- Or you can use RX with plain variables/events and rewire your events into IObservable without any 'Subject' and "OnNext"'ing if you dont like them..
- or...